# Shared Libraries in Same Folder with App in TCSH

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, tcsh

I am deploying a locally-compiled app to a remote Linux server. Since I don't have root account I cannot put needed shared libraries to /usr/lib
Is there a way to overcome this? I put libraries in same folder and changed "path" variable but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple options.

1. You can set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable inside your script (see [Section 3.3.1.](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) of the shared libraries HOWTO). There are [problems](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) with this approach for production code, but if set in a wrapper script is probably ok.
2. You can call your app with the libraries specified on the command line by invoking the [`ld-linux` program loader](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) directly, as described in the manpage and HOWTO:

   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path PATH EXECUTABLE